# Track cusor  location and add image from cusor location into PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

I'm looking for the most appropriate way to allow the user to import an image to a PDF and allow them to drag the picture around the PDF/winform and specify where the image is placed.

I'm thinking the best way to go about doing this is pulling the location from the cusor.

Something like:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(400, 772, 545, 792);
```

Instead of pre-defined coordinates, have the output be the **selected cursor location of the user.**

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users might have a hard time picking an image location just by pressing the mouse cursor on a form. Instead I recommend allowing them to drag a relatively sized rectangle around a grid. You'll have to translate coordinates appropriately, including fixing the `Y` value since iTextSharp starts at the bottom left instead of the top left, but that shouldn't be too hard.

Below is a full working C# 2010 WinForms app that allows you to drag a red rectangle around a black square. The comments in the code should pretty much explain everything. It has one big problem that need to be addressed, it stores the X/Y coordinates are screen-based and not form based, so if you drag once, move the entire form and drag again it will get "funky". This can be solved by calculating the x/y relative to the form instead which I'll leave up to you.

Hopefully this gets you down a path that works for you!

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Basic dimensions of our "border" and our "image". Assumes 72 dots per inch which isn't technically correct but gives us something to work with
        private int BORDER_WIDTH = (int)11 * 72;
        private int BORDER_HEIGHT = (int)8.5 * 72;
        private int IMAGE_WIDTH = (int)2 * 72;
        private int IMAGE_HEIGHT = (int)3 * 72;
        private int IMAGE_OFFSET = 5;

        //These will store the x/y when we press our mouse down so that we can calculate the drag later
        private int offsetX;
        private int offsetY;

        //Our main "image" that we'll move around
        PictureBox pb;
        //The "border" to move the image around in
        PictureBox border;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Resize the form and make it not user-resizable
            this.Size = new Size(BORDER_WIDTH + 30, BORDER_HEIGHT + 50);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;

            //Create our "image"
            pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.Size = new Size(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
            pb.Location = new Point(IMAGE_OFFSET, IMAGE_OFFSET);
            pb.BackColor = Color.Red;
            //Bind a handler to the mouse down event
            pb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.pbMouseDown);
            this.Controls.Add(pb);

            //Create our "border"
            border = new PictureBox();
            border.Size = new Size(BORDER_WIDTH, BORDER_HEIGHT);
            border.Location = new Point(IMAGE_OFFSET, IMAGE_OFFSET);
            border.BackColor = Color.Black;
            this.Controls.Add(border);
        }
        private void pbMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Store the current x/y so that we can use them in calculations later
            offsetX = e.X;
            offsetY = e.Y;
            //When the mouse is down we want to remove the original mouse down handler
            pb.MouseDown -= new MouseEventHandler(this.pbMouseDown);
            //Add to more handler looking for mouse up and mouse movement
            pb.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(this.pbMouseUp);
            pb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.pbMouseMove);
        }
        private void pbMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //When the mouse button is released, remove old handlers and add back the down event
            pb.MouseMove -= new MouseEventHandler(this.pbMouseMove);
            pb.MouseUp -= new MouseEventHandler(this.pbMouseUp);
            pb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.pbMouseDown);
            //Pop up a message, this is where something with iTextSharp would be done
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The top left of the image is at {0}x{1}", pb.Top - IMAGE_OFFSET, pb.Left - IMAGE_OFFSET));
        }
        private void pbMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Calculate where to draw the "image" at next
            //First, calculate based on the current image's location, the offset that we stored ealier and the current mouse position
            int newLeft = e.X + pb.Left - offsetX;
            int newTop = e.Y + pb.Top - offsetY;
            //Next, make sure that we haven't gone over one of the boundaries of the "border"
            if (newLeft < border.Left) newLeft = border.Left;
            if (newTop < border.Top) newTop = border.Top;
            if (newLeft + pb.Width > border.Right) newLeft = border.Right - pb.Width;
            if (newTop + pb.Height > border.Bottom) newTop = border.Bottom - pb.Height;
            //Finally, assign the new value
            pb.Left = newLeft;
            pb.Top = newTop;
        }
    }
}
```